# Build matrix from smaller matrices or rearange list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, matrix

Start with the fact that I am a new user of Mathematica, and this is my problem:

I have a complex simbolic matrix A (rectangular, 14x14), and I want to build a matrix from its imagenary and real parts, such as:

```
{{A_R, -A_I},{A_I, A_R}}//MatrixForm
```

I have tried that:

```
ReV[x_] := Refine[Re[x], _Symbol \[Element] Reals]; 
ImV[x_] := Refine[Im[x], _Symbol \[Element] Reals];
expandedMatrix = {{ReV[A], - ImV[A]}, {ImV[A], ReV[A]}};
```

But this gives me, under MatrixForm, a matrix of matrices, while I just want a single rectangular matrix which I can use as coefficients matrix of a system of linear equations.

Is there a different way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 2;
A = Array[x, {n, n}] + I Array[y, {n, n}];
A // MatrixForm
B = ComplexExpand[ArrayFlatten[{{Re[A], -Im[A]}, {Im[A], Re[A]}}]];
B // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  x(1,1)+ \mathrm{i} \, y(1,1) & x(1,2)+ \mathrm{i} \, y(1,2) \\
>  x(2,1)+ \mathrm{i} \, y(2,1) & x(2,2)+ \mathrm{i} \, y(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$
>
> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  x(1,1) & x(1,2) & -y(1,1) & -y(1,2) \\
>  x(2,1) & x(2,2) & -y(2,1) & -y(2,2) \\
>  y(1,1) & y(1,2) & x(1,1) & x(1,2) \\
>  y(2,1) & y(2,2) & x(2,1) & x(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Comment: As I mentioned, I am new to this program and I don't know the difference between array an matrix. In my code, I have used "DiagonalMatrix" to crate the basic matrix and then I've used "ReplacePart" to put things in other places in the matrix. So your saing I need to change it to array?

Comment: No need for special treatment: In Mathematica, matrices are simply arrays (or tensors) of tensor rank 2. And arrays are simply nested `List`s of list in rectangular shape.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to solve the problem by using the function "Join":

```
Join[Join[Re[A], - Im[A], 2], Join[Im[A], Re[A], 2]] // MatrixForm
```

"Join[list1,list2]" concatenates in column direction, while "Join[list1,list2,2]" concatenates in row direction.